Derivation of second order Taylor expansion formula
Suppose that $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is twice differentiable  and has a continuous second derivative on an open interval $(a,b)$.
If $x$ and $x+h$ belong to the interval, prove that
$$F(x+h)=F(x)+hF'(x)+\frac{h^2}2F''(x)+h^2\phi(h)$$
for some $\phi$ where
$$\lim_{h\to0}\phi(h)=0.$$
(Stein's Fourier Analysis, 2007 version, Exercise 8 of Chapter 1)

My own answer following the Stein's hint.
Since $F'(x)$ is differentiable at $x$,
$$\lim_{k\to0}\frac{F'(x+k)-F'(x)}k = F''(x).$$
Let $\psi(k)=\frac{F'(x+k)-F'(x)}k - F''(x)$ so that $F'(x+k)=F'(x)+kF''(x)+k\psi(k)$ and
$$\lim_{k\to0}\psi(k)=0$$
Denoting $k=y-x$, we have
$$F'(y)=F'(x)+(y-x)F''(x)+(y-x)\psi(y-x).$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align*}
F(x+h)
&=F(x)+\int_x^{x+h}F'(y)\,dy\\
&=F(x)+\int_x^{x+h}\left(F'(x)-xF''(x)\right)+yF''(x)+(y-x)\psi(y-x)\,dy\\
&=F(x)+\left(F'(x)-xF''(x)\right)h+F''(x)\left(xh+\frac12h^2\right)+\int_x^{x+h}(y-x)\psi(y-x)\,dy\\
&=F(x)+hF'(x)+\frac{h^2}2F''(x)+\int_x^{x+h}(y-x)\psi(y-x)\,dy.
\end{align*}
$$
So I can take
$$\phi(h)=\frac1{h^2}\int_x^{x+h}(y-x)\psi(y-x)\,dy$$
Now, it is enough to prove that $\phi(h)\to0$ as $h\to 0$, or,
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{h^2}\int_x^{x+h}(y-x)\psi(y-x)\,dy=0.
$$
But I don't know how to calculate the limit.

Is it clear that $\psi$ is integrable?

@Gary It is continuous and thus (Riemann) integrable. In the above definition $\psi$ is not defined at $k=0$. But it can be easily extended : $\psi(0)=0$. So it is indeed continuous.

@Gary Maybe, continuous second derivative can be required in order for $\psi$ to be continuous when $k\ne0$. The continuity of second derivative is actually assumed in the original exercise. I'll add the hypothesis.

Let's define
$$
g(h)=\frac{1}{h^2}\int_x^{x+h}(y-x)\psi(y-x)\,dy=\frac{1}{h^2}\int_0^h u\psi(u)\,du.
$$
Then,
$$
\lvert g(h) \rvert \le \max\Biggl\{\frac{1}{h^2} \int_0^{\lvert h \rvert} u \lvert \psi(u) \rvert \, du,\quad \frac{1}{h^2} \int_0^{\lvert h \rvert} u \lvert \psi(-u) \rvert \, du\Biggr\}.
$$
Now, since $\lim_{u\to 0} \psi(u)=0$, we know that, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert \psi(u) \rvert < \epsilon$ for all $-\delta < u < \delta$. Therefore, if $-\delta < h < \delta$,
$$
\lvert g(h) \rvert \le \frac{1}{h^2} \int_0^{\lvert h \rvert} u \epsilon \, du = \frac{\epsilon}{h^2} \int_0^{\lvert h \rvert} u \, du = \frac{\epsilon}{h^2} \frac{h^2}{2} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
Summarizing, we have shown that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that, if $-\delta < h < \delta$, then $\lvert g(h) \rvert < \epsilon/2$, which is the same as saying that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} g(h) = 0.
$$
This should finish your proof. However, I believe this is not the most straightforward way to prove the result - you can have a look here for other approaches.

Thanks. I understand the whole procedure except for the second inequality. This assumes the following statement : If $P(h)=\int_0^hp(x),dx$ and $h$ is real, then $|P(h)|\le\int_0^{|h|}|p(x)|,dx$. If $h>0$, the inequality holds. But if $h<0$ I can't find a way to prove the thing. Substitution rule can not well be applied. Instead, maybe I can use an alternative ; If $P(h)=\int_0^hp(x),dx$ and $h$ is real, then $|P(h)|\le\int_{-|h|}^{|h|}|p(x)|,dx$.

In this new statement, integrand is greater than or equal to the former and is nonnegative. And the integration interval is now guaranteed to be greater than or equal to the last one, so that the inequality holds. (But if you can, can you explain the inequality?) I'll choose your answer (Thank you) and write my own answer.

You're right, the inequality assumes some kind of symmetry $\lvert p(-x) \rvert \le \lvert p(x) \rvert$ which is not necessarily true. I'll fix the answer using a different approach, just to edit less, but yours is perfectly fine.

Thanks. And I also checked your modified answer. Have a nice day!

So defined
$$\phi(h)=\frac1{h^2}\int_x^{x+h}(y-x)\psi(y-x)\,dy$$
can be modified by the substitution rule ($y-x = u$) ;
$$\phi(h)=\frac1{h^2}\int_0^hu\psi(u)\,du$$

L'Hopital Rule

$$
\lim_{h\to0}\phi(h)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h\psi(h)-0}{2h}=\frac12\lim_{h\to0}\psi(h)=0.
$$

$\epsilon$-$\delta$ reasoning, thanks to dvdgrgrtt

Fix $\epsilon>0$.
Since $\psi(h)\to0$ as $h\to0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $-\delta<u<\delta$, then $|\psi(u)|<\epsilon$.
If $-\delta<h<\delta$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
|\phi(h)|
&\le\frac1{h^2}\int_{-|h|}^{|h|}|u||\psi(u)|\,du\\
&\le\frac\epsilon{h^2}\int_{-|h|}^{|h|}|u|\,du\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, $\phi(h)\to0$ as $h\to0$ as desired.
